# Terraform Snowflake Provider Configuration Inconsistencies

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently seeing some inconsistencies when running the `snowflake-labs/snowflake` provider.

There are two different ways that credentials are provided to the provider. The first is via `~/.snowflake/config`, the second is via environment variables.

When running `terraform plan` while using `~/.snowflake/config` I get the messaging that no changes have been detected, as expected, however when using the environment variables, terraform complains of drift (specifically a snowflake storage integration with s3), and then further on I get the following error `Error: object does not exist or not authorized` for a Snowflake database that is there.

The infrastructure was initially provisioned using `~/.snowflake/config` to authenticate.

I need to be able to get this working with the environment variables for running terraform in CI/CD.

Below are my configurations:

**WORKING WITH ~/.snowflake/config**

Provider block in `main.tf`

```
provider "snowflake" { 
  profile = "default" 
  role      = "ACCOUNTADMIN" 
}
```

Contents of `~/.snowflake/config`

```
[default]
account='<REDACTED>'
user='<REDACTED>'
password='<REDACTED>'
role='ACCOUNTADMIN'
```

**NOT WORKING WITH ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**

Provider block in `main.tf`

```
provider "snowflake" {
  role = "ACCOUNTADMIN"
}
```

Environment variables:

```
SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT="<REDACTED>"
SNOWFLAKE_USER="<REDACTED>"
SNOWFLAKE_ROLE="ACCOUNTADMIN"
SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD="<REDACTED>"
```

Any thoughts on to what I may be missing the the environment variables case would be greatly appreciated.

After multiple changes to the environment variables I know that Snowflake is authenticating properly (it didn't with different combinations of what I thought possible account values could be).

I expect the generated plans to be identical regardless of the methodology that the provider was configured with.

As mentioned above configuration with environment variables results in an error generating the plan, indicating that resources have been changes and not available/not authorized.

Comment: The error messaging leads me to believe this has something to do with the role being selected / permissions that is being handled differently depending on the configuration mechanism.

Comment: FYI, versions 0.74.0 and 0.75.0 of the provider are borked. As of now the latest working version is 0.73.0. Not sure if that's your problem, FYI.